# How do I teach high positions for double bass?

Tags: technique, fingering, fretboard, fingerstyle-bass

I am self-taught on electric bass and I'm currently working with a double bassist who learned to play in a much more conventional sense than I did. My musical education consists of watching videos of other people do things an emulating them, so while my bass skills are natural to me, I have trouble articulating these thoughts to others.

A particular jazz chart we are both working on uses many high notes and octave(+) intervals. Due to my experience playing notes like this, I was able to work out ideal fingering patterns. I tabulated these [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYH1V.png) for reference.

My co-bassist, however, has no experience with using high positions. As she was taught to play traditional orchestra music, she does not have a good understanding of how bassists use the different possible fingerings of each note to make pieces easy, or even possible, to play. In general, she only uses one fingering for each pitch and does not know of ways to find alternate fingerings on different strings.

I'll describe an example. In the piece [I linked above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYH1V.png), the only way she knew how to play the first part of measure #1 was by sliding between 3rd position F on the D string and 10th position F on the G string; she did not realize that 8th position on the A string could be substituted for the first F.

I am eager to teach her the process to finding the easier ways to fret pieces of music, and she is eager to learn, but I have hit a roadblock since I cannot communicate the internal tricks I use to find optimal fingerings. Can anyone recommend a good strategy (or refer me to some resources) for teaching these tricks?

Comment: Can you edit to elaborate a bit more on the “roadblock”? You want to teach, she wants to learn —is the problem with how to communicate? With her ability to execute the techniques?

Comment: @AndyBonner My issue is an inability to understand the theory behind how I decide fingerings and how to project that to others. Additionally, I'm having trouble finding online resources to support me in teaching her the strategy. I've explained this better now in the first paragraph.

Comment: And I'll also add that I have full confidence that she can learn and execute the technique with enough practice; she's very skilled and confident at the big band pieces she's playing now.

Comment: Why don’t you post the chart in question and add a little more detail about the trouble areas, for example: “I play bars 7-9 on the D and G strings between frets 9 and 13”? It’s hard to figure out what you know and what you’re trying to convey to her,

Comment: …Also keep in mind that at a certain point in the upper register upright bass players will switch to thumb position which isn’t necessary on electric bass.

Comment: Thanks! Please use the "Edit" button below the question to add to the question itself, though; comments aren't part of the question.